# Create unique personal id

Tags: grouping, stata

I have a Stata data set like this:

```
HouseholdId  PersonId OtherVariables
1               1
1               2                 
2               1
2               2
3               1
3               2
```

Here `HouseholdId` is a unique identifier for each household and `PersonId` is a unique identifier for each person in a household. If I want to create a unique personal id for each person within the sample, period. How would I do this?

I have tried `egen per_id = group(PersonID HouseholdID)`
but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I've made some edits correcting inconsistencies in variable names and some other details. If I have changed your intent you will need to edit yourself.

Comment: "doesn't seem to work" is never a good problem report. Why "seem"? What happened? Why is it wrong? Why is it not what you want?

Answer (score 1):

I take it that you want a unique identifier for each person within the entire dataset. That could be just

```
sort HouseholdId PersonId 
gen long obs Id = _n
```

as follows from an accessible discussion [in this Stata FAQ](http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/creating-group-identifiers/). That would have been found by typing in Stata

```
search identifier
```

or even

```
search id
```

(Meta-answer: You can and should look within Stata for information on basic notions like this.)

I add a strong recommendation that the word **unique** still carries its original meaning of appearing once only. The word **distinct** is, I suggest, a much better word when that is what you mean. More on that on p.558 of [this paper](http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=dm0042).